# AngularJS - pagination is not working for bootstrap datatable

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, pagination, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am working with the AngularJS bootstrap datatable and am very new to that.

Here is my code

controller.js

```
.controller('tableContactCtrl', function($timeout, $scope, $filter, $sce, ngTableParams, tableService) {
        //var data = tableService.data;

        var selfContact = this; 
        $scope.data = [];
        var promise = tableService.getContactData();

        promise.then(
            function(payload) { 

                $scope.data = payload.data;

                selfContact.tableEdit = new ngTableParams({
                    page: 1,            // show first page
                    count: 10,           // count per page  
                    sorting: {
                        name: 'asc'     // initial sorting
                    }                   
                }, {
                    total: $scope.data.length, // length of data
                    getData: function($defer, params) {
                        //$defer.resolve(selfContact.data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));

                        //sorting                       
                        var orderedData = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')($scope.data, params.orderBy()) : $scope.data;

                        //filtering
                        var orderedData = params.filter() ? $filter('filter')(orderedData, params.filter()) : orderedData;

                        //orderedData = orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());

                        params.total(orderedData.length);
                        //$defer.resolve(orderedData);
                        $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));

                    }
                });                 
            },
            function(errorPayload) {
              $log.error('failure loading movie', errorPayload);
            }); 

        //to update data    
        selfContact.updateContact = function(w) {
            tableService.updateContactData(w);
        }   

        selfContact.removeContact = function(id, contact_id) {
            //alert(id)
            $timeout(function () {
                $scope.data.splice(id, 1);
            })
            //tableService.removeContactData(contact_id) 
        }           
    })
```

view.html

```
<div class="container" data-ng-controller="tableContactCtrl as tctrl">
  <table ng-table="tctrl.tableEdit" class="table table-striped table-vmiddle" show-filter="true">
    <tr ng-repeat="w in data"  ng-class="{ 'active': w.$edit }">
       <td>...</td>
       <td data-title="'Actions'">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-if="!w.$edit" ng-click="tctrl.removeContact($index, w.contact_id)"><i class="zmdi zmdi-close"></i></button>
       </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

I have 5000 records in DB so I need pagination in datatable. When I use 'this' variable instead of $scope variable in controller, pagination is working good but I can't get what is the issue with $scope. When I use $scope variable it loads all the data in one page so it's taking much time also and ofcourse it's not convinient to load all records in one page. Can anyone please help me?

**UPDATED**

controller.js

```
$scope.tableEdit = new ngTableParams({
    page: 1,            // show first page
    count: 10,           // count per page  
    sorting: {
        name: 'asc'     // initial sorting
    }                   
}
```

view.html

```
<div class="container" data-ng-controller="tableContactCtrl as tctrl">
    <table ng-table="tableEdit" class="table table-striped table-vmiddle" show-filter="true">
    ...
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: add the code with `$scope`, which is giving you error.

Comment: It's not giving any error but am getting all the records in one page. And I have added all the code above in controller.js

Comment: if you use $scope, remove controller as from view,
`<div class="container" data-ng-controller="tableContactCtrl">`, then use
`<table ng-table="tableEdit" class="table table-striped table-vmiddle" show-filter="true">` without `tctrl`

Comment: Okay! but in controller am using selfContact.tableEdit. And if I use $scope.tableEdit in controller, am not getting any data from DB.

Comment: can you paste the current code?

Comment: change `<div class="container" data-ng-controller="tableContactCtrl as tctrl">` to `<div class="container" data-ng-controller="tableContactCtrl">`

Comment: I added updated code. I can't remove tctrl from view as am using tctrl.removeContact and tctrl.updateContact functions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128028/discussion-between-sravan-and-user7).